# image not displayed in html5 table on cloud9 for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, image, cloud9-ide

Here is my code where I put in an img tag to show a picture.  I saw from another answer I'm supposed to put the full path.  Can someone show what that is when you use Cloud9?

```
<h1>CandyPages#home</h1>
<p>This is the home page for the
<img src="assets/images/slide-1.jpg" alt="Top-Selling Sweets"   
 width="600"  height="350">
candy app
</p>
<p>Find me in app/views/candy_pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem probably has nothing to do with Cloud9, cloud9 is just the development kit you are using. Are you seeing a broken image icon in your browser?

**9 times out of 10, the reason for a broken image in the browser is because the image url is not correct.**

Have you tried using erb's image_tag helper? The rails asset pipeline is a wonderful thing once you start to understand it. Here is some instructions on using the image_tag() helper instead of HTML's img src

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

I would try substituting:

```
<img src="assets/images/slide-1.jpg" alt="Top-Selling Sweets"   
width="600"  height="350">
```

with instead:

```
 <%= image_tag("slide-1.jpg", size: "600") %>
```

Comment: That was awesome!  Thank you too for the link!

Comment: no problem, I love to help! Would you mind check marking my answer as the correct answer? (There is a check mark to the left of the up down arrows)